# vuedraggable - dragging is right aligned

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For some reason, when I drag my items, the content are right aligned (the mouse is on the red circle). Is there any particular reason for this?

[image]

My code is simply this:

```
<Draggable
    v-model="data"
    handle="[name=dragger]"
>
    <ItemDetailRow
        v-for="(detail, index) in data"
        :key="index"
        :detail="detail"
        @delete="deleteOne(index)"
    />
</Draggable>
```